# Bash alias doesn't work in cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, windows-8.1, alias

Can someone please explain to me how to set up bash aliases? I am using cygwin on windows 8.

I added `alias my_first_alias='git status'` at the end of `/.bashrc` file. Typing `my_first_alias` into cygwin results in `-bash: my_first_alias: command not found`.

Trying to restart cygwin, running `. .bashrc` doesn't help with that.

Comment: If, even after you run `. .bashrc`, it still doesn't work then you either didn't `.` the file you edited or didn't edit the file you thought you did. Make sure you edited the same file that you sourced with `.` and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your alias command is correct and should be working as long as the alias command is actually being executed.  It sounds like your .bashrc file is not being loaded when you start your bash shell.  Make sure you have the following in your ~/.bash_profile file:

```
[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
```

Also make sure that the location of .bashrc and .bash_profile are in your home directory.  Above you have referenced /.bashrc.  I doubt "/" is your home directory.  You can determine the location of your home directory from the shell by entering the command:

```
cd; pwd
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems I confused home path with root path. Now, when I get rid of the alias, it still recognises it, until I restart cygwin, any ideas why is `. ~/.bashrc` doesn't do the job?